# Знак минуса: слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, цифры, знак-минус

Как правильно?

`–1.`

`– 1.`

А если число пятизначное и более, то как?

`–100 000.`

`– 100 000.`

`–100000.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, это вопрос полиграфический, а не орфографический. Прямого отношения к форуму он не имеет.

"Грамота" отвечает так:

> "Знаки математических действий и соотношений отбивают от смежных
> символов и чисел на 2 пункта, а знаки положительности или
> отрицательности значения величины набирают слитно с последующим
> числом". См.: А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова, Справочник издателя и
> автора. М., 2003. П. 6.4.4.

То есть:

100 - 100 = 0,

но

-100 + 100 = 0

Что касается разрядности, то 4 цифры пишутся слитно, а от пяти уже пишутся с пробелом:

1000,

но

10 000

10 000 000
и т.д.

Comment: А с пяти- и более разрядными числами как знак минуса писать? Всë-таки пробел число содержит — может, и минус будет отбиваться.

Comment: @Максим  Смотрите, минус обычно примыкает к числу, чтобы было ясно, что он относится именно к нему. Мне не встречалось указаний на то, что минус надлежит в каких-то случаях писать отдельно. Отбивается пробелами именно минус в качестве арифметического знака. В конце концов, даже в длинных числах с минусом вы получите максимум четыре сплошных символа (-1000), а остальные будут отбиты. Полиграфическое правило как раз и заключается в одном — не использовать 5 и выше знаков слитно.

Comment: Не особо понял. 100 000 — пятизначное число. А пятизначные пишутся с пробелом. Тогда знак минуса с пятизначным будет слитно или раздельно? __Итоговый вопрос: как верно: _–100 000 или – 100 000_?__

Comment: Если ответите на последний вопрос, я приму ваш ответ.

Comment: @Максим 100 000 — шестизначное число. Оно пишется с пробелом между разрядами, но без пробела перед знаком. Поэтому верно: -100 000

Comment: Ладно, я принимаю ваш ответ.